# FileNotFoundException when accesing Properties.Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, filenotfoundexception

I've got a project with several pictures in a `Resource.resx` file. All pictures are set to in .resx embedded. `Resources.resx` file AccesMode is public.

I can access my pictures in design time without any errors. For example:

```
global::Controls.Properties.Resources.gruen;
```

When I run my project, I getting this:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "The file or assembly"
>   Controls.resources, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = de-DE, PublicKeyToken
>   = null "or a dependency was not found. The system cannot find the file specified."

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dependency on the assembly "Controls.resources". You can add this on your projekt-explorer. Just right click on your assembly -> add -> dependency. There you should be able to add the dependency

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Controls.resoures.dll is not a part of the project. The resources I'm using are embedded in Controls.dll which is part of my project an also is added as reference. That's my problem. Obviously it should work, but it doen't.